# MVC pattern: what needs to be created first?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, testing

I'm studying CodeIgniter and its software patterns. Which should be created first, the view or the controller?

Comment: In general, I agree with @Shiplu that the question is too broad. However, I think it actually resulted in some positive answers, so it's useful just this once. I would suggest passers-by check out some of the different answers provided.

Comment: The number of different answers is interesting.  So I think good question.  Personally I think much of this depends on the simplicity of the project and the amount of resource in the team.  I think a lot of single developers will move quicker working top down, ui to model.  And in some companies the specifications will be wire-frames or HTML.  I doubt there is a fits all correct answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The **Model** because that is your application. Controller and View only form one interface to the Model. One could say, the controller is the door to your house. What do you build first? The door or the house? Right, so build the Model first. Then add an interface to it.

Comment: +1 This is how we 'generally' work, I think it leads to a better developed model/api, and aids TDD.  Occasionally we break process and work top down though, usually when we have poorly defined requirements, or excessive stake holder involvement and demonstrations.  It also allows the backlog to be separated across multiple developers / designers more easily  i.e backend / ui.

Answer (score 8):

I always **start with View**. The scenario is, I have already designed my database, have chosen technologies. This is my workflow on MVC pattern.

1. Create html template with CSS/image etc.
2. Depending on what data is shown on view I create Controller methods.
3. I put dummy data in controller methods so that I can see a dynamic page that manipulates the view properly.
4. According to the data my controller needs I creates Model method.

In this process I never create any extra method or code block. It prevents to add code that we usually think "might be necessary". But they are never needed.

In this way you are creating specification first then implementing it on each step. So its like, View creates data requirements for it. Controller provides it. And creates data specification to Model. At last Model just provide only those data which are called or needed.

Comment: +1  This is a perfectly valid top down approach.  Surely works well when up front logic specification or model design is missing / not considered a valid use of effort.  It all depends on circumstance and QA requirements.  For many applications nothing could be easier or faster then working top down.

Comment: +1 In the old days, when we used notepad to preapre static pages, we all used the design first-apprach. In the old days it made perfect sense though it is probably very much based on personal choice. I believe if you are developing a project on your own this makes a perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Controller is must. Because you can't execute/get the work done without having a controller. So controller comes first because of following,

1. You can disable the view when necessary
2. You can set relevant variables to the view via controller
3. Interaction with the model is doing by the controller, so when you require data the controller comes first
4. You can redirect the user to other controller
5. You can display other view based on the request. For computers view A, and for mobile devices view B, like wise
6. View is the presentation, so first you need data to present.

Answer (score 1):

Though the question already has an accepted answer I'd like to offer an approach from a testability standpoint. Ready-made frameworks *often* don't design their controllers with testability in mind, so this sort of question arises over and over.

A well-written, ***testable*** controller should take the view as a dependency injected via the controller's `__construct` method. I don't know if CodeIgniter controllers allow for this functionality, though.

In the MVC paradigm the Controller "brings together" the elements of the View and the Model, so, like any behavioral dependency, if these objects provide any functionality beyond "dumb" data storage, they should be injected into your controller at the time of instantiation so that they can be mocked for testing purposes. So you would do something like the following:

```
$view  = new SmartyView;
$model = new UserModel;
$controller = new LoginController($view, $model);
```

Often, the model doesn't provide any public "behavior" methods and acts as a basic data storage entity. If this is the case, for the same reason you don't need to inject an array data structure into your controller to create new arrays, you can safely create new model instances inside your controller without sacrificing testability:

```
class LoginController
{
  protected $view;

  public function __construct(ViewInterface $view)
  {
    $this->view = $view;
  }
  public function doLogin($user, $pass)
  {
    $userModel = new UserModel();
    // do stuff with model to determine if user/pass was valid
  }
}

$view  = new SmartyView;
$controller = new LoginController($view);
```

For testability, the best practice is to avoid tightly coupling your controllers to your views and models. This is why you should generally avoid using the `new` keyword inside your controller code. Your controller -- and any other object, for that matter -- should **ASK** for its dependencies, not **LOOK** for them. This will result in more transparent APIs, more testable code, less debugging hassle and a happier you.

Comment: This part confuses me a bit. How would you end up providing the relevant information to the control during the request lifecycle? 

Generally speaking, a router/dispatcher does a very simple call like 

`$route->set('/uri/to/match', 'ControllerName', 'controllerAction');`

What you're describing is something that would be enormously tedious to code in a big project, which involves applying some anonymous function to the router/dispatcher which then handles the instantiations before passing them to the controller. And what if a model depends on other models?

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be old question ,but I bumped into it now.
 And someone else might need it later. So I decided to summarise it. 
 I think that your approach will depend on situation.
 Let the order of operations you make be this **Model-View-Controller** 
And lets call it ***Bottom-To-Top*** approach. The case and reasoning for this is provided by @Gordon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9249986/4615778) . 
And another case lets call it ***Top-To-Bottom***, when you start with UI. The case and reasoning for this is provided by @shiplu.mokadd.im [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9250035/4615778). 
Evaluate your own case and choose one of them. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The controller, you need it to communicate between the model and the view.
Without the controller the model cant interact with the view.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with Controller as it is calling View.

Here you can see that Controller is intermediate between Model and View.
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

Answer (score 0):

I would say model and controller hand in hand.

Without model, how will you know what will be the flow in the controller?

Without controller, how will you know what methods are needed in model?

Sometimes, model gets priority, sometimes controller depending upon the situation.